# Can not install or run glxgears from Ubuntu USB

Tags: live-usb

I am new to ubuntu, I have installed ubuntu on USB and booting from it,
I wanted to test my graphics card so want to run glxgears tool ..
When I type the command as below to install the package it gives the messages below. The ubuntu is running from usb, please advise why this is not installing.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils 
Reading package    lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state    information... Done
Package mesa-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is
missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Is this a Persistent USB? Graphics drivers are loaded before the Persistent casper-rw file/partition. But all new stuff on a Persistent USB is stored in casper-rw so proprietary graphics drivers do not work. Try a Full install instead, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step